# Why don't moles repair their DNA?

Tags: dna

Cells have mechanism to repair damaged DNA. So why don't the cells in moles (the spots), repair themselves and the moles dissappear?

Comment: What makes you think that moles are caused by DNA damage? Please cite the source of this information.

Comment: @David because people get moles from sun damaged skin. So I put 2+2 together.

Comment: Let's try again. Are you asking why the known mechanisms of repair of e.g. UV damage to DNA are not 100% efficient, or are you thinking that the DNA repair mechanisms somehow detect that the DNA has been changed in the mutated cells (e.g. the transformed skin cells) and can reverse this ("repair themselves")? If all mutations got repaired there would be no evolution.

Comment: @David Let's not.

Comment: As is appropriate for a comment on a question that is unclear and lacks detail, I asked for clarification on specific points. If you had made this clarification I would have attempted to answer your question. As you refuse to do without giving any reason I have no option other than to vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

[DNA repair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_repair) is a collection of processes by which a cell identifies and corrects damage to the DNA molecules that encode its genome. However it is yet to be linked closely to mammalian moles.

[Information here](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/traits/moles), states:

> "Moles are overgrowths of skin cells called melanocytes, but the genetic factors involved in their development are not well understood."

The *BRAF* gene is one of the most well-studied genes involved with benign moles, if a mutation arises in this gene - there may be a production of an altered protein that causes melanocytes (melanin-producing cells located in the bottom layer of the skin's epidermis) to aggregate into moles.

I cannot answer why DNA repair does not occur. Maybe the cell cannot identify the mutation, maybe the cell cannot corrects the damage, or maybe it is also from environmental factors. This is an active area of research, but receives far less attention compared to cancer or heart disease.